# realvnc raspberry pi licencing (signin for remote connection)

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, debian-buster

All the instructions ive found online say to go to licencing, then to use log in details and the device will appear in the viewer. but i've no licencing tab....

its a pi 4 running buster vnc ver 6.5.0

[missing licencing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSNlp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use Vnc Server on my raspberry pi with raspbian Buster, and I never needed to go in the licensing tab.

Just type the IP address of your raspberry pi (in your case `192.168.0.106:1`) in the address bar of Vnc Viewer and connect to it.

If it doesn't work, give more information about your problem because I don't completely understand what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I meant remotely, not on the same network but over the internet.